# Object for view not being passed if initiated in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble passing an object to another view when surrounded by a UINavigationController. For example, when I use the following code, everything works fine, the currentUser for the first view is passed to the second view.

```
    ProfileViewController *pvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileVC"];
    pvc.currentUser = currentUser;

    [self.drawerController setCenterViewController:pvc];
```

But when I encapsulate pvc in a UINavigationController, the currentUser does NOT get passed, shown below. Does the navigation controller overwrite / create a new instance of ProfileViewController somehow?

```
    ProfileViewController *pvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileVC"];
    pvc.currentUser = currentUser;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pvc];

    [self.drawerController setCenterViewController:navigationController];
```

(BTW the drawerController is from MMDrawer and method basically sets the designated view as the center).

Edit (declaration of user):

```
Contact *currentUser = [Contact fetchContactWithLinkedinAccount:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"linkedinAccount"] inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
```

in Contact.h:

```
+(Contact *)fetchContactWithLinkedinAccount:(NSString *)account inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"linkedinAccount == %@", account];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

Contact *fetchedContact;
for(Contact *contact in fetchedObjects) {
    fetchedContact = contact;
}

if(fetchedContact != nil) {
    return fetchedContact;
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

}

Comment: `UINavigationController` doesn't recreate your rootViewController. Show declaration of your currentUser property.

Comment: it seems to be object-specific. I can pass a string.

Comment: Yes, show the declaration, it could be getting released.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `currentUser` property declared like this:

```
@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Contact * currentUser;

@end
```